# Why eclipse link fails?

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse

i try to link libmysql.lib and mysqlclient.lib files with eclipse. To do that,

in GCC C++ Linker,

i choose Libraries and select lib directory which includes  libmysql.lib and mysqlclient.lib files.

But this does not work. because i still get this error

```
/home/mert/workspace1/Project484/Debug/../src/main.cpp:99: undefined reference to `mysql_init'
/home/mert/workspace1/Project484/Debug/../src/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
```

what is the problem?

Comment: I would guess that as well as the library directory you also need to tell eclipse the names of the libraries. It's not going to automatically link with the libraries just because they're in that directory. With g++ you would use the `-lmysql -lsqlclient` options. Not sure exactly how you do this in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project | Properties | C/C++ Build | Settings | Tool Settings | GCC C++ Linker | Libraries and add `mysql` and `mysqlclient` there.

BTW, the right linker flags can be acquired by running this on console:

```
mysql_config --libs
```

You can trying adding this line to Project | Properties | C/C++ Build | Settings | Tool Settings | GCC C++ Linker | Miscellaneous. I'm not sure it'll work, though, since I've never tried it.

(Same goes for compilation flags: they're acquired by running `mysql_config --cflags`.)

*EDIT*

Apparently, trying to link windows libraries under linux was the problem.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysql
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient i get this error

Comment: i put full path but still does not work /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhome/mert/workspace1/Project484/src/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/mert/workspace1/Project484/src/lib/mysqlclient

Comment: i guess you should add directory with -L and library name with -l.

Comment: @user2232205, try renaming `mysqlclient.lib` to `libmysqlclient.lib`

Comment: not working. It tries to compile with like that g++ -L"/home/mert/workspace1/Project484/src/lib" -o "Project484"  ./src/main.o   -lmysql -lmysqlclient does not work

Comment: Wow, I've just noticed: your libraries are for Windows, but your paths are definitely unix-like. Which platform you're on? Libraries for Linux should have `.a` extension (static libraries, anyways).

Comment: i use Linux .s  do i need to download mysqldriver for linux?

Comment: If by that you mean linux version of `mysql` and `mysqlclient` libraries, then yes.